# Xamarin.Forms Javascript not working in android platform

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have Xamarin.Forms project and I have to inject object from my code to Html code it working just fine in Xamarin.iOS but not in Android platform

```
    webView.Source = LoadHTMLFileFromResource();
                webView.Navigated += (sender, e) => {
                    webView.Eval("var x = document.getElementById('versionCode').innerHTML = '" + versionBuild + "';");
                };

private static HtmlWebViewSource LoadHtmlFileFromResource()
        {
            var source = new HtmlWebViewSource();
            var assembly = typeof(AboutPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("about_us.html");
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                source.Html = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            return source;
        }
```

my tries to fix this issue to make custom render for web view

and in android project

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);


            if (Control == null)
            {
                var webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(Forms.Context);
                webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                SetNativeControl(webView);
            }

        }
```

but still not working I can run my script at my code, what I miss

Answer (score 0):

I figure the answer, for some reason  `webView.Navigated` not called

```
 webView.Navigated += (sender, e) => {
                    webView.Eval("var x = document.getElementById('versionCode').innerHTML = '" + versionBuild + "';");
                };
```

so I add CustomWebViewClient to my customer render and override `OnPageFinished` method to execute my javascript code at this method

```
    public class CustomWebViewClient : WebViewClient
            {
                string javaScriptCode = "javascript:document.getElementById('versionCode').innerHTML = '" + "Version: " +
                                        GetAppVersionBuild() + "';";

                public override void OnPageFinished(Android.Webkit.WebView webView, string url)
                {
                 // UPDATE my answer to work in previous version before kitkat 
                   if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
                {
                    webView.EvaluateJavascript(javaScriptCode, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    webView.LoadUrl(javaScriptCode);
                }
                }


            }
```

my custom render class

```
 protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
            {
                base.OnElementChanged(e);


                if (Control == null)
                {
                    var webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(Forms.Context);
                    webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                    SetNativeControl(webView);
                }
                if (e.NewElement != null)
                {
                    Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                    Control.SetWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
                }


            }
```

I hope this helps anyone face the same issue